# SOAPUI testrunner test properties from command line

Tags: soapui, test-runner

I have a very large data dump that I call from a WSDL endpoint (Over 200mb) and I can get it to download manually by running a test in SOAPUI. Now I'm trying to automate the call and insert it into the task scheduler in Windows 10. I've built my command line call like this:

```
 testrunner.bat -c "GetAll" E:\SOAPUI\project.xml
```

As I watch it execute the call I see OpenJDK spool up to 1.3Gb of memory and then disappear with no output. When I run a different, smaller data call to the same endpoint everything works fine. I remember in order to get the original TestRequest in SOAPUI to run I had to expand the 'Max Size' variable to 8000000000. How do I do that from the testrunner.bat command line call? I see project properties are called with -P. Is there a different argument tag for TestRequest properties?

Answer (score 1):

The memory settings for Java when using TestRunner are found in testrunner.bat. Right-Click and edit, and change the following line as necessary:

```
 set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128m -Xmx1024m -Dsoapui.properties=soapui.properties "-Dsoapui.home=%SOAPUI_HOME%\"
```

In my case I changed -Xmx1024m to -Xmx8G. This change allows the max memory to go to 8 GB.